# ReactJS: Need to change card styling using onClick function

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, onclick

I know this will need a refactor later to separate things out into their own components, but I'm up against a time crunch at the moment and need to wire this up as is. I used array.map() to create card elements from a JSON object I'm using for testing purposes. I'm attempting to use an onClick function on a card `<div>` to save some identifiable information like 'offerid' into the component state and then check if the id in state matches the current card. If it matches, I want to add cardActive as the className on the div so that only that specific card changes color. I'm not sure how to do this. As it is now, all card stylings are updated no matter which card is selected. My React component and corresponding CSS are listed below. Any help would be hugely appreciated

React

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import './Button.css';

class UsersList extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
            cardActive: false,

            customers:
            [
                {
                    "CustomerId": "1",
                    "LastName": "Doe",
                    "FirstName": "Jane",
                    "Address": {
                      "Address1": "1811 Chestnut Street",
                      "Address2": null,
                      "City": "Philadelphia",
                      "State": "Pennsylvania",
                      "Zip": "19103"
                    },
                    "Offers": [
                      {
                        "OfferId": "Offer1",
                        "Name": "Offer 1",
                        "Products": [
                          {
                            "ProductId": 1,
                            "ProductName": "Stuff"
                          },
                          {
                            "ProductId": 2,
                            "ProductName": "More stuff"
                          }
                        ],
                        "Price": "$1"
                      },
                      {
                        "OfferId": "Offer2",
                        "Name": "Offer 2",
                        "Price": "$2",
                        "Products": [
                          {
                            "ProductId": 3,
                            "ProductName": "A lot of stuff"
                          },
                          {
                            "ProductId": 4,
                            "ProductName": "And then there was stuff"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "OfferId": "Offer3",
                        "Name": "Offer 3",
                        "Price": "$3",
                        "Products": [
                          {
                            "ProductId": 5,
                            "ProductName": "Good grief would you look at all this stuff"
                          },
                          {
                            "ProductId": 5,
                            "ProductName": "What a great deal for stuff"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
              ]
        }
    }

    selectCard(){
        this.setState({ cardActive: !this.state.cardActive })
    }


    render (){
        let card_class = this.state.cardActive ? "cardActive" : "card";
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.customers.map((customer, index) => {
                    return  <div key={index + customer.CustomerId}>
                                <h2>Customer</h2>
                                <hr></hr>
                                    <h3 >Name: {customer.LastName}, {customer.FirstName}</h3>
                                    <h3 >Customer ID: {customer.CustomerId}</h3>
                                    <h3 >
                                    Address: 
                                    <br></br>
                                    {customer.Address.Address1}
                                    <br></br>
                                    {customer.Address.City}, {customer.Address.State} {customer.Address.Zip} 
                                    </h3>
                                    <br></br>
                                    <h2>Available Offers</h2>
                                    <Grid container spacing={24} justify="center"> 
                                    {customer.Offers.map((Offer,index) => {
                                        return <div key={index + Offer.OfferId} onClick={this.selectCard.bind(this)}>
                                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                                <div className="card" class={card_class}>
                                                    <div className="container">
                                                        <h5><b>{Offer.OfferId}</b></h5> 
                                                        <h2>{Offer.Name}</h2>
                                                        {Offer.Products.map((Product, index) => {
                                                            return <div key={index + Product.ProductId}>
                                                                    <p>+ {Product.ProductName}</p>
                                                                  </div>

                                                        })}
                                                        <h3>{Offer.Price}</h3> 
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </div>
                                    })}

                                    </Grid>

                            </div>

                })}
                <button className="navbuttonSelected">Submit</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default UsersList
```

CSS

```
  .card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-radius: 5px; /* 5px rounded corners */
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-right: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .cardActive {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.01s;
    border-radius: 5px; /* 5px rounded corners */
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-right: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    background: #0c72c5 !important;
    color: white !important;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .cardActive:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }

  .card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }
```

Comment: If you're setting state based on a previous value in state, you should call it as a function: `this.setState((state) => ({ cardActive: !state.cardActive }));` That way you never get messed up by order of state setting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set id of selected card:

```
selectCard(offerId) {   
  this.setState({ cardActive: offerId });
}
```

change how `onClick` is called and apply specific class when `Offer.OfferId === this.state.cardActive`

```
return (  
 <div
   key={index + Offer.OfferId}
   onClick={() => this.selectCard(Offer.OfferId)}
 >
   <Grid item xs={12}>
     <div
      className={Offer.OfferId === this.state.cardActive ? "cardActive" : "card"}>
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/mjryv01528

Comment: This is the best approach IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two approaches to fix your problem.

Approach 1:

- In your selectCard method, in addition to cardActive, store the Id of card into state.
- In your render method, in map function, consider Id(saved in state ) also to either apply your cardActive class.
- With this approach, you will not be able to select multiple cards at a time. Only one card will be having cardActive class and others will not.
- Also, you need to make sure you set Id to state only when card is selected. Not when its deselcted.

Approach2:

- In your offers object of customer, in addition to having all the existing fields, add a property isActive and use this in your map method to either set cardActive class or the normal one.
- Whenever a card is selected, update isActive property of the selected card (you can pass the offerObject to selectCard method and update isActive property in it or you can pass a unique identifier and use your customers object and update isActive property of selected object.
- With this approach, you can have multiple cards selected as you are maintaining isActive at each customer level rather than one cardActive variable.

Comment: Approach 1 sounds like the way to go but how would that look in code? I updated my constructor to include
`this.state = {
clickedId: -1,
}`
changed my `selectCard` function to this:
`selectCard(event){
        const id = event.target.offerid
        this.setState({ 
            cardActive: !this.state.cardActive,
            clickedId: id
        })
        console.log(this.state.clickedId);
    }`
and changed the onClick to
`onClick={this.selectCard}`

but now when I click all I'm getting in the console is -1 and then undefined whenever I click

Comment: Rather than sending only event, why not send offer Id and the customer ID selected? You can use the selected offerid and customer ID (if needed) to identify which offer is selected and apply styles to that card

Comment: That was actually going to be my next question, how would I do that? My end goal is to pass both offerId and Customer ID to a function that sends a POST action when the user clicks submit

Comment: Will you be having only 1 card active at a time? if thats the case, you can maintain customerId and offer id in state and send it to POST action when user clicks submit. If not I would suggest go with the second approach where you can select all the active cards using isActive property within the customers/offers object and send those ids to your POST method

Comment: Yeup only 1 card selected at a time! I need to pass the following unique values from the initial JSON response (SessionID, CustomerID, Offers {OfferID, OfferName}) back in that POST action. Would I update my state then to look like:
`this.state = {
        cardActive: "",
        customerID: " ",
        Offer: " ",
        OfferID: " ",
        OfferName: " ",
        customers: [...]
    }`
and then bind them to state in a function like:
   `submitSelection(offerId, offerName, CustomerId, SessionId, ){
        this.setState({ offerId: , offerName, CustomerId, SessionId});
    }`

Comment: It did but now I've got another problem haha. I can't map the selection and the other customer values to a function to send back via POST. Do you have any idea how to do this? Someone suggested I use a data object to pass the values back into it but I'm getting undefined everytime the function fires

Comment: Strange!! Would you edit your question or create  a new one if possible so that we can take a look at what you are passing and where the value is becoming undefined?

Answer (score 0):

```
...
constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
        cardActive: "",

        customers: [...]
    }
    this.selectCard = this.selectCard.bind(this);
    this.getCardClass = this.getCardClass.bind(this);
}

selectCard(offerId){
    this.setState({ cardActive: offerId })
}

getCardClass(offerId) {
    const { cardActive } = this.state;
    return offerId === cardActive ? 'cardActive' : 'card';
}
```

```
render() {
...
    customer.Offers.map((Offer,index) => {
        return <div key={index + Offer.OfferId} onClick={() => this.selectCard(Offer.OfferId)}>
            <div item xs={12}>
            <div className="card" class={this.getCardClass(Offer.OfferId)}>
                <div className="container">
                    <h5><b>{Offer.OfferId}</b></h5> 
                    <h2>{Offer.Name}</h2>
                    {Offer.Products.map((Product, index) => {
                        return <div key={index + Product.ProductId}>
                                <p>+ {Product.ProductName}</p>
                              </div>

                    })}
                    <h3>{Offer.Price}</h3> 
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    })
...

}
```

Here the selected card is stored in the state instead of just the it being `true` or `false`. The `selectCard` helper method sets the value of `cardActive` while `getCardClass` determines the selected card's class.